# What should I do if I already have a small metal Shivalinga?

Tags: shiva

I was 14 years when out of devotion I bought a small metal Shivling from a pilgrimage. But I got to know that Shivling is not kept at home. I am unable to worship it daily, especially I am unable to do even a simple abhishek daily. I read and heard that this is not a good thing to keep Shivling and not worshipping. I also read that we cannot also put the Shivling out of house as it is insult to Lord Shiva. It's not that I am not devoted to Lord Shiva , but I am unable to do daily poojan to the Shivling. What should I do? Can I keep it in a temple, our should I flow it in river, or should I keep it at home , or what. Please guide and help me come out of this sorrow.

Comment: Give it in any Shiva Temple if you are not able to do Puja. if you want to keep Shiva Linga in house, you must do Abhisheka to it, at least on Mondays.

Comment: start doing simple worship like incense and applying sancalwood etc. it will take only 4-5 mins

Comment: Are you that busy that you can't even bath it daily? I think even the Prime Minister of India can take out that much time from his busy schedule..:D.. For eg, why don't you just wake up one hour early than you usually do?